# How to configure setuptools_scm to always generate timestamp and git hash

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setuptools-scm

The [`setuptools_scm`](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools_scm) package by default could generate 4 different version messages.

```
no distance and clean: {tag}
distance and clean: {next_version}.dev{distance}+{scm letter}{revision hash}
no distance and not clean: {tag}+dYYYYMMDD
distance and not clean: {next_version}.dev{distance}+{scm letter}{revision hash}.dYYYYMMDD
```

In my usecase, I don't want to use its version message. Instead, I want to use it and retrive git hash and timestamp information.

```
from setuptools_scm import get_version
my_version = get_version()
```

According to its documentation, there is a `get_version()` function. But if the current repo has no distance and clean, it only generates `tag` which is not enough.

My question is how to configure `get_version()` function to let it always generate git hash and timestamp. So I can parse it and create my own version message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this [issue](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools_scm/issues/809), the author suggests a way to do it. More examples would be added later.